# How to use CNContactPickerdelegate to pick multiple numbers in one contact in objective c?

Tags: ios, object, cncontactpicker

How to select multiple numbers in one single contact by using with cncontact picker delegate ? 
i am using  below method  but i couldnt able to select numbers
- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContactProperty:(CNContactProperty *)contactProperty;

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved my issue long back , posting lately 
this is my answer it may helpful for other thats why i am posting here.

```
#pragma mark - CNContactPickerViewController Delegate method implementation
(void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContact:(CNContact *)contact
{
    NSMutableArray *contactNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    selectedName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",contact.givenName];
    NSLog(@"%@",selectedName);
    NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name : %@ %@ %@\n",contact.givenName, contact.familyName, contact.organizationName];
    //    // 1.  (Phone Numbers)
        tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@phoneNumbers : ",tempString];
       // NSArray*phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers;
        for (CNLabeledValue *phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers)
        {
          CNPhoneNumber *phone = phoneNumber.value;
            tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<%@>",tempString,phone.stringValue];
             [contactNumberArray addObject:phone];
            selectedPhNumber=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phone.stringValue] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
             NSLog(@"%@",selectedPhNumber);
        }

         //2.  (Emails)
        tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n Email : ",tempString];
        for (CNLabeledValue *email in contact.emailAddresses)
        {
            selectedEmail=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", email.value];
            tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<%@>",tempString,email.value];
               [contactNumberArray addObject:email];
             NSLog(@"%@",selectedEmail);
        }
 [self sendRefferelDetailsToServer];

}
```